# How can I resolve an Object Reference error when calling Steps from my Step Definitions

Tags: c#, specflow

I have some steps I want to call in specflow from some of my step definitions.

The problem is the line `Given("I run a useful step");` doesn't work. I get the error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Steps.Given(string)`.
```

But I'm doing what it says on the wiki.

Here is my setup:

```
[Binding]
public class Utility_Subtests:Steps
{
    [Given(@"I run a useful step")]
    public void IRunAUsefulStep()
    {
        //Some useful things
    }

    [When(@"I want to use a useful step")]
    public void IWantToUseAUsefulStep()
    {
        Given("I run a useful step");
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work as it's almost exactly the same as they show in examples.

**Updated:**

I resolved this issue by removing the "static" in one of my methods. Silly me.

**Update 2:** More Info

So basically before each feature I want to run code that will login to our trading system and delete a company, then restore it. I already have the "steps" to do this so I simply wanted to call these steps within the `BeforeFeature` method.

I can call the methods... but then I can't use: `string attribute = ScenarioContext.Current.CurrentScenarioBlock.ToString();` because it's not in a scenario context if that makes sense as its running this before the feature.

Here is one of my typical test steps:

```cs
[When(@"I ICE to the test account: ""(.*)""")]
public static void Subtest_IICEToTestAccount(string iceAccount)
{
    try
    {
        OpenVMSDriver.SendShellCommand("ICE SET " + iceAccount);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { TestDriver.CatchNTrash(ex); }
    string attribute = ScenarioContext.Current.CurrentScenarioBlock.ToString();
    string attrValue = Utility.GetAttributeValue(attribute);
    TestDriver.ResultsLog.LogSubTest(attribute + " " + attrValue.Replace("(.*)",iceAccount));
}
```

What this does is send a command to VMS and gives me a log of what took place. In order to get some nice detail I capture the current scenario block and then read the value of the attribute and write those out to a log.

The problem is if I just called this method like this: `Subtest_IICEToTestAccount("Faster");`

I wouldn't be able to read the current attributes they would throw an exception.

So I wanted to use the `When("I ICE to the test account: FASTER");` but I was getting the error in the title. Maybe this isn't the best way to do it and I should just write a method that handles all of the steps to delete and restores companies.

Comment: Any reason for the minus comment?

Comment: What is `Given` ? is it an attribute or a method?

Comment: Its a method in SpecFlow but its an abstract method as far as I can see. I'm going off the example on github: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions

Comment: Hmm. Compiles for me, using the latest SpecFlow package.

Comment: looks like it should work to me, although I'm not sure I have tried calling steps in the same class before, I can't see why that might make a difference. Is this a compile time or runtime error?

Comment: Its a compile time error. How strange! Im using version 1.9.0.77 of the SpecFlow dll.

Comment: Oh dont I feel silly... I had "static" in one of my methods... I removed it and now it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You should change it as

```
[Binding]
public class Utility_Subtests:Steps
{

    [Given(@"I run a useful step")]
    public void IRunAUsefulStep()
    {
        //Some useful things
    }

    [Given(@"I run a useful step")]
    [When(@"I want to use a useful step")]
    public void IWantToUseAUsefulStep()
   {

    }

}
```

Comment: This will create a ambiguous step definition to have duplicate `Given` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This also feels like a code smell. Why are you running a `Given` step inside a `When` step? Even if it's an extra line of code, keep your `Given`, `When` and `Then` steps fully separate:

```
Scenario: I test something useful
    Given I run a useful step                  # 1. Set up
    When I want to use a useful step           # 2. Act
    Then something useful should have happened # 3. Assert
```

What if you want to use `When I want to use a useful step` without the test setup that `Given I run a useful step` provides?

If you really need a certain `Given` run each time, you might need to organize your scenarios with a Scenario Background:

```
Scenario Background:
    Given I run a useful step                  # 1. Set up

Scenario: I test something useful
    When I want to use a useful step           # 2. Act
    Then something useful should have happened # 3. Assert
```

Comment: Well the problem is if I have 10 scenarios I dont want the background run for each one. The background needs to be run just 1 in the "BeforeFeature" section. I just wanted to use existing steps to achieve this. But it didnt really look possible to do.

Comment: I could the function directly of course but then id lose the context of the step being called. And I do capture the content of these steps for logging purposes

Comment: How do you lose the context of the step being called? Are you using `ScenarioContext.Current`?  Can you post more of your step definitions and how you want to use them? I think we need some more background on your problem.

Comment: Updated with more info